# Structure Map 2.6.2 scoping

Tags: dependency-injection, scope, inversion-of-control, structuremap, httpcontext

I'm moving my application from Structure Map 2.5.3 to 2.6.2 and I'm having some scoping problems.

In 2.5.3 version I used `CacheBy(InstanceScope.HttpContext)` to have instances disposed at the end of Http request. Now in 2.6.2 I tried both `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` and `HttpContextScoped` but my injected instances do not get disposed.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you sure that the objects were disposed in 2.5.3? Structure map do not dispose the objects unless you call `ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015354/structuremap-disposing-of-datacontext-object) and other related questions.

Comment: Yeah, they were disposed. I found a bug. Those classes were in another project still referencing 2.5.3. It works fine now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes which were not disposed were in another project still referencing 2.5.3. It works fine now after fixing the references :)